# How to attach event handlers in custom react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a project in which I have to display graphs. So I decided to use vis.js for this purpose. [react-vis-network](https://github.com/lifeomic/react-vis-network) is a custom component for react to use vis.js. Now I'm struggeling to attach event handlers like I would normally do. You can find a hint at [this section](https://github.com/lifeomic/react-vis-network#extending-custom-clusters-and-custom-modules) but I don't know how to manage properly.

In my manual attempt to use vis.js with react I would attach event handler like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.network = new Network(this.appRef.current, this.state.data, this.state.options);
    this.network.on("stabilizationIterationsDone",  () => {
        this.network.setOptions( { physics: false } );
        console.log(this.network.getSeed());
    });
}
```

I have found following snippet code in react-vis-network's [Network.js](https://github.com/lifeomic/react-vis-network/blob/master/src/Network.js)

```
...
const eventPattern = /^on([A-Z])(.*)$/;
...
Object.keys(this.props)
      .filter(prop => prop.match(eventPattern))
      .forEach(prop => {
        const event = prop.replace(
          eventPattern,
          (match, p1, rest) => p1.toLowerCase() + rest
        );
        // Props controlled by developer
        // eslint-disable-next-line security/detect-object-injection
        this.network.on(event, this.props[prop]);
     });
     ...
```

But I don't know how to provide for example:

```
this.network.on("stabilizationIterationsDone",  () => {
        this.network.setOptions( { physics: false } );
        console.log(this.network.getSeed());
    });
```

Hope you can give me a hint.

**Update:**
I think it has to be something like the following. But it doesn't work yet.

```
...
const props = {};
    props.onStabilizationIterationsDone = function(){console.log("test")};
....
return (
    <div id='network'>
    <Network props={props}>
```

Comment: The regexp looks like it would match something like `onStabilizationIterationsDone` for the event name. `'on'` followed by a capital letter, A-Z.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it with a online regex tester but can't figure in which way I have to pass the handler.

Comment: `this.network.on("onStabilizationIterationsDone"`

Comment: or `<Network onStabilizationIterationsDone={this.handleStabilizationIterationsDone} />`

Comment: Thank you very much. This did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event pattern is looking for a prop starting with `'on'` followed by a capital letter A-Z. Format your prop like the component expects:

```
<Network onStabilizationIterationsDone={this.handleStabilizationIterationsDone} />
```